# Convert SQL date to javascript date

Tags: javascript

Everything works fine except for 1 date. This is my function.

```
export function formatDate(date) {
  console.log(new Date(date), date);
  let d = new Date(date),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getUTCDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [month, day, year].join('/');
}
```

I tried to log it in console and this is the result.
[image]

I have underlined the wrong date. It says may 1 eventhough its april 30. This is probably caused by the timezone. Does it mean that new Date().getMonth() can't be trusted?

Comment: JS date calculations are weird at times. Try using the moment js library. It's dedicated for date operations only so is much more accurate and simple to use.

Comment: Its just about timezone. The time with "Z" postfix indicates a UTC time format, and when you parse it using `new Date()` it gives you in local timezone based on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates are UTC (indicated by the `Z` at the end of the time string), but you are outputting them in your local timezone `(Philippine Standard Time)` which is `GMT+0800`, hence the difference in outputs (which you'll notice is exactly 8 hours). This is caused by your `console.log`
calling `Date.toString()` on the result of `new Date(date)`, which outputs the datetime according to the client timezone.

If you want to get the same result as your SQL date, use [`Date.toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) instead:

```js
let d = new Date('2021-04-30T21:30:15.697Z')
console.log(d.toString())
console.log(d.toUTCString())
```

Similarly, you need to use [`Date.getUTCMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) and [`Date.getUTCFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear) to get the correct month from the SQL date:

```js
let d = new Date('2021-04-30T21:30:15.697Z')
console.log(d.getMonth())
console.log(d.getUTCMonth())
```